# CSS3 border-image

Tags: css

Do I need some special DOCTYPE when I want to use CSS3 ? I have div with dashed border and I want to set border-image (only can with CSS3), but when I set border-image:url(.., nothing happens.

Comment: Mozilla, but I need to make to work on all of them

Comment: You will not get it to work on all browsers, and since it is cosmetic you shouldn't *need* to either. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Oh, and if you really are using a browser called Mozilla, then it must be at least 5 years old since it was renamed to SeaMonkey in 2005 (to avoid being confused with the organisation that publishes it, and Firefox, and Thunderbird as well as various other software projects). Did you mean Firefox? If so, which version?

Answer (score 4):

Some browsers may only support CSS 3 features in [Standards Mode](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/), but a standards mode triggering Doctype should be considered business as usual and not "special".

Keep in mind that CSS 3 is a collection of specifications that have **not** yet reached recommendation stage. They are very new and browser support is far from universal (and isn't a binary state of 'supports CSS 3 or not' — the current versions of all the major web browsers support some of CSS 3 (for different values of 'some'). Your problem could simply be that you aren't using a browser that supports `border-image`.

Answer (score 2):

> border-image currently works in **Safari
>   and Firefox 3.1** (Alpha). The syntax to
>   use it is:
>
> *border-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27
>   27 round round;*

[See demonstration page](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 is not available on all browsers at this time. Right now, only Chrome, Opera, and Safari support it. CSS3 commands will not work on IE; you'll have to find other work-arounds or wait until browsers catch up with the standards.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the border-image did not show up, because you didn't use the correct prefixes.
Right now, just "border-image" is not supported by major browsers, hence you need to add the prefix for the browser.

E.g.

```
-webkit-border-image
-moz-border-image
-o-border-image
```

- `-webkit` - for WebKit-based browsers such as Google Chrome and Safari
- `-moz` - for Firefox
- `-o` - for Opera

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a specific DOCTYPE, but `border-image` is only supported in some browsers. You can also use:

```
-webkit-border-image
-moz-border-image
-khtml-border-image
-o-border-image
```

to broaden the range of support for browsers. CSS3 has not been implemented as a standard across all current browsers, so using specific CSS tags is the best way to go for now.

Answer (score 0):

Support is very limited and inconsistent across the browsers that do support it. Check Quirksmode (bottom of the table) to see the bad news http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html